# Ravendb "Where IN" query not working as expected

Tags: ravendb

I don't understand why Q2 would not return results if Q1 does. Am I missing something?

```
var q1 = session.Query<Comp>().Where(x => x.ptype=="RTC"||x.ptype=="FLT"); //works

var q2 = session.Query<Comp>().Where(x => x.ptype.In(new string[] {"RTC","FLT"})); //does not
```

Comment: What build are you using?
Can you show a full failing test?

In should certainly work.

Comment: This was happening because I was using a 2.0 client against a db on RavenHQ (which is using v1.0). I really wish someone hosted v2.0 already!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I was using a 2.0 client against a db on RavenHQ (which is using v1.0).